# Currenza C2 coin reader MDB adapter for Android device

Tags: android, adapter

The Currenza C2 is a vending machine coin reader that uses a multidrop bus (MDB) interface. I wish to create a vending machine using the Currenza C2 B6M for coin reading, and connect it to an Android tablet as the interface.

I can't find the hardware required to connect a vending machine to an Android device. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Would a Raspberry Pi with a touch-screen be acceptable instead of an Android tablet? You may have better luck connecting an interface like MDB to a device like that because there is a larger availability of interfaces and third-party hardware around the Raspberry Pi. Such as [this module](https://www.abrantix.com/MDBConverter_en.html).

Comment: Do you already have the tabled you want to use? Because it seems that there are specialised devices like [this one](https://www.inhandnetworks.com/products/inpad-7-touchscreen-all-in-one.html) (and of course, the raspberry pi, as mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is either a direct Multi-Drop to USB converter or a Multi-Drop to RS232 converter which can then be converted to USB. As far as I know Android exposes the serial port API. There are many such devices, one example would be [this.](https://blog.abrantix.com/webshop/product/mdb-converter-3/)